# Error when using net user with get-content lines

Tags: powershell

I have a list of IDs/Users in a file that looks like this:

- iduser1
- iduser2
- iduser3

---

I am trying to run net user *ID* /domain on each of the IDs but get an error each time.

Here is my code:

```
$userlist = get-content "U:\USERIDS.txt" 
    foreach ($id in $userlist) {
     net user $id /domain | Select-String "Workstations allowed"
}
```

When I try this, I get an error:

net : The syntax of this command is:

```
   net.exe : The syntax of this command is:
   At line:4 char:5
   +     &net user "$id" /domain | Select-String "Workstations allowed"
   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The syntax of this command 
   is::String) [], RemoteException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

   NET USER
   [username [password | *] [options]] [/DOMAIN]
     username {password | *} /ADD [options] [/DOMAIN]
     username [/DELETE] [/DOMAIN]
     username [/TIMES:{times | ALL}]
```

I assume this is because a string is not being passed in $id so I tried this with no luck either:

```
$userlist = get-content "U:\USERIDS.txt" 
foreach ($id in $userlist) {
    $newID = "" + $id
     net user $newID /domain | Select-String "Workstations allowed"
}
```

Any ID on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This is probably related to your user data. Try &-syntax: `&net user "$id" /domain | Select-String "Workstations allowed"`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  There is rarely a need to use old `cmd.exe` commands.

Comment: The code in the error does not match the code that you posted. The error indicates that you are using a variable named $line.

Comment: You've not posted the error completely. When you face an error with Net User, the first line and the last line of the error contains some other information as well. For example for the first line of the error: `net : The user name could not be found.` and the last line `More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2221.`

Comment: A problem with `$id` shouldn't produce a PowerShell error. Please show your actual code and error message.

Comment: I have added the full error code. The $line was a typo.  I am trying to gather workstation names that the ID has access to. Net User is the easiest way I know how to do that. 

Additionally, I took a look at my input file and it had spaces after each line and once I removed the trailing spaces the code worked. I will look for a way to cleanup my source data which is coming from a sequential file on z/os